# Negate the statement “If $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd, then $m$ or $n$ is odd”

Tags: logic, proof-writing, number-systems

I need to negate this statement somehow

> If $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd, then $m$ or $n$ is odd.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: When you say "negate", do you mean that you are looking for a logical negation of the statement, or that you are looking for a proof that the statement is false?

Comment: Not sure what you want.  The logical negation would be "There exist two even numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd."  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be "$\gcd(m,n)$ is odd", $B$ "$m$ is odd", and $C$ "$n$ is odd". The original statement is equivalent to $\neg A \vee (B \vee C)$. To negate it, we have
$$\neg[\neg A \vee (B \vee C)], \textrm{ which is equivalent to}$$
$$A \wedge \neg (B\vee C), \textrm{ which is equivalent to}$$
$$A\wedge \neg B\wedge \neg C$$
Therefore, the negation is "$\gcd(m,n)$ is odd but both $m$ and $n$ are even", which is obviously a wrong statement.

Answer (score 1):

> If $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd, then $m$ or $n$ is odd.

There is a tacit universal quantifier here:

> For all values of $m$ and $n,$ if $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd, then $m$ or $n$ is odd.

The following are equivalent:

> It is not true that ror all values of $m$ and $n,$ if $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd, then $m$ or $n$ is odd.
>
> There exist values of $m$ and $n$ for which it is not true that if $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd, then $m$ or $n$ is odd.
>
> There exist values of $m$ and $n$ for which $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd and it is not true that either $m$ or $n$ is odd.
>
> There exist values of $m$ and $n$ for which $\gcd(m,n)$ is odd and $m$ is not odd and $n$ is not odd.